Do the mountains stop the earth from shaking?
Does Quran 21:31 mean the mountains prevent the earth from moving also same with Jami` at-Tirmidhi 3369 can someone explain it to me? Because the verse says that the mountains prevent the earth from moving and I am confused.
Quran 21:31

And We have placed firm mountains upon the earth so it does not shake with them, and made in it broad pathways so they may find their way

Jami` at-Tirmidhi 3369

The Prophet said: “When Allah created the earth, it started shaking. So He created the mountains, and said to them: ‘Upon it’ so it began to settle.


I wonder what exactly is meant by moving/shaking in this context. First of all, earth is not a stationary object, it's hurling through space at a staggering speed as well as spinning on it's own axis. If it means earthquakes, mountains sure don't prevent them as we still have them.
The quoted hadith is at odds with established science on how earth was formed.

@TruthSeeker418 what makes it at odds?

@truthseeker418 check my reply idk if it tagged you

Sorry I don't visit this site daily. The statement that after earth was created "it started shaking" is at odds. You can read here how earth was actually formed - https://news.uchicago.edu/explainer/formation-earth-and-moon-explained#:~:text=The%20Earth%20formed%20over%204.6,space%20to%20form%20the%20moon.

still doesnt seem at odds to me can u explain

Earth didn't "start shaking" when it was formed, nor did mountain had any effect on the primordial earth

i already wrote a reply explaining it but it got removed can i dm u

Sure, please go ahead
